# Add to custom methods to method signature autocomplete

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When in a class there is the ability to autocomplete certain methods, e.g. the constructor or some inherited functions. I'd like to add some custom methods like `public function foo():void` to the autocomplete if a specific trait is applied. First I thought of Live Templates but they cannot be constrained to be only applied if there is a certain trait present.

Do you have any idea how I could achieve this? Maybe by generating some docblocks?

Comment: PHPDoc `@method` annotations?

Comment: This doesn't allow autocomplete when I'm declaring new methods in the class.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean here. Please try illustrating your issue with code sample (text) + screenshot of how it works for you. Cannot speak about using `@method` in a Trait but declaring such methods on a class works fine (quite a few frameworks/libs use that to help IDE with framework's internal magic).

Comment: @LazyOne Plesase take a look the the image [here](https://i.imgur.com/yFAuP3D.png). I want to inject custom method signatures into the autocomplete for new methods if the trait `AsAction` is present in a class without writing a plugin. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So ... you want to have a whole method declaration completion, so that the IDE offers `public function foo(): void` kind of line to complete? Try `@method` PHPDoc tag on a trait -- an example: https://i.imgur.com/ixZmKyv.png

Comment: BTW: what theme do you use?

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. If you copy this and make it an answer I will accept it as a solution.
I'm using Monokai Pro (Filter Machine).

Comment: Thanks for the theme name. As usual: looks great on screenshot .. but very hard to get used in the actual editor (inconvenient: different and partially limited colors compared to what I have in my custom light theme so it's difficult to read the code, errors and warnings are highlighted differently  harder to spot etc; looks better on screenshot than in the editor -- somehow colors are not that smooth (could be the font family and size + the rendering). Need to try it for a few full days...

Comment: The old problem with a new IDE theme. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@method` tag](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md#57-method) in PHPDoc comment for the trait to declare such "virtual" methods. Modern PhpStorm versions can offer such signature when invoking code completion when declaring a new method.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * @method void traitPublic()
 */
trait T
{
    private function traitPrivate(): void
    {
    }
}

class C
{
    use T;
}
```

[image]